# Converting SQL Server stored procedure with declared table to Linq 2 Entities

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I'm having a bit of trouble converting a SQL Server stored procedure into a Linq query. I've read over several tutorials that make it seem pretty simple. But part of the stored procedure involves running a function to populate a table declared within the procedure, like so:

```
DECLARE @userOrgs TABLE(OrgId INT, OrgActiveFlag BIT)

INSERT INTO @userOrgs(.......)
    SELECT OrgId, OrgActiveFlag 
    FROM someFunction
```

The function that populates the table has already been converted to C#, so I can call that within my class where I'm implementing the rest of the procedure. When I get to the query, there's a bunch of inner joins to do, and because this temporary table is defined as a var, I don't have access to OrgId to do the last join. Here's the FROM block to be converted:

```
FROM USER_ActiveUsers AU
INNER JOIN USER_Users U ON U.Id = AU.UserId
INNER JOIN AUTH_UserIdentities UI ON UI.Id = U.Id
INNER JOIN CVRS_ClientVars CV ON CV.UserId = U.Id
INNER JOIN ORGN_Orgs O ON O.Id = CV.Value
INNER JOIN @userOrgs UO ON UO.OrgId = O.Id
```

and here is what I have so far. The last join is saying 'object' doesn't contain a definition for "OrgId":

```
var records = from au in activeUsers
              join u in users on au.UserId equals u.Id
              join ui in userIdents on u.Id equals ui.Id
              join cv in clientVars on u.Id equals cv.Id
              join o in organizations on cv.Value equals o.Id.ToString()
              join ao in accessibleOrganizations on o.Id equals ao.OrgId
```

How do I make it so that OrgId is accessible so I can do the last join?

Comment: can you post how are you creating accessibleOrganizations.

Comment: `var accessibleOrganizations = userOrganizations.Execute(sqlParameters) as List<object>;` where userOrganizations is an instance of the function's class

Comment: you need to check accessibleOrganizations list by placing a break point if it contains the OrgId. I am sure it does not that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: I know I don't have access to it as it is a var. The rest of my SQL Server tables are defined as Lists<'tableName'>, for example clientVars is a List<ClientVariables>. But those are all existing tables, not one declared within the procedure. Other examples I've seen use "into" and then another "from", but I lose access to o.Id when I tried that

Comment: Where are all your navigation properties? You shouldn't be doing **any** joins at all.

Comment: I did not understand, "I don't have access to it as it is a var." you can very well debug it and also add it to watch and check the value.

Comment: Robert - I'm not entirely sure where those are/what those are. I'm at a new job(i.e. my company hired a computer engineer who's good at hardware to help develop framework), I posted as little as I could because I didn't wanna post anything proprietary